# How to print the time with AM/PM format in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to print the time from date picker but with the AM/PM. I can print the time, but it never prints the AM/PM. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this document for more information [NSDateFormatter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
.An example could be:

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSLog(@"date=%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: Yes it help me very much ..... i actually i just want to adjust the size of date picker with 12hr and 24hr time format .. and its really help me .. Thank you

Answer (score 22):

Use below lines of code

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];   
    NSString *str_date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"str_date:%@",str_date);
```

Comment: Thank u, this solved my issue :)

I want to ask you question: how to parse date came from API like these
2014-03-06T00:00:00+0200

This is my code:
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];

but it came with nil all the time, Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set your DateFormatter `amSymbol` and `pmSymbol` as follow:

**Xcode 8.3 • Swift 3.1**

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a 'on' MMMM dd, yyyy"
formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"

let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())
print(dateString)   // "4:44 PM on June 23, 2016\n"
```

Edit: 
Objective C Code

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
df.AMSymbol = @"AM";
df.PMSymbol = @"PM";
df.dateFormat = "h:mm a 'on' MMMM dd, yyyy"
NSString *stringDate = [df stringFromDate:dateFromString];
```

Ref link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31469237/2905967

Answer (score 1):

Date to String

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@“dd-MMM”];
cell.dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:item.pubDate]
```

> Date Format Symbols
>       The table from the unicode date formatting page should be enough for you to build your own desired date format string…

```
Pattern Result (in a particular locale)
yyyy.MM.dd G ‘at’ HH:mm:ss zzz  1996.07.10 AD at 15:08:56 PDT
EEE, MMM d, ‘’yy    Wed, July 10, ‘96
h:mm a  12:08 PM
hh ‘o’‘clock’ a, zzzz   12 o’clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
K:mm a, z   0:00 PM, PST
yyyyy.MMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa 01996.July.10 AD 12:08 PM
Hope this is useful to someone out there.
```

Use the following link for more datails.

http://benscheirman.com/2010/06/dealing-with-dates-time-zones-in-objective-c/

this really helped me. It was really easy.

Answer (score 0):

for printing AM/ PM the parameter `a/aa/aaa` all will work.

```
NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[myDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm aaa"]; //a,aa or aa all will work.
[myDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm aa"];
NSString *myDate = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"myDate is :%@",myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in swift 5

```
    var strDate1:String = "2019-12-19 05:42:04";
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate1)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"
    let strigDate =  dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!)
```

Output: `2019-12-19 05:42:04 AM`